# Check if objects type inherits an abstract type

Tags: c#, types

Say I have an object, `someDrink`. It could be of type `CocaCola` or `Pepsi` which both inherit the abstract `Cola` (which inherits `Drink`) or any kind of drink for that matter. I have a method that returns a string of the most preferred beverage.

```
public string PreferredDrink(Drink someDrink)
{
    var orderOfPreference = new List<Type> {
        typeof (Cola),
        typeof (PurpleDrank),
        typeof (LemonLimeBitters)
        ...
    }

    foreach (drinkType in orderOfPreference) {
        if (someDrink.GetType() == drinkType) {
            return someDrink.ToString()
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Water will be fine thank you");
}
```

The code above will not work, because the type of `someCola` can never be *equal to* an abstract type. Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
if (someCola is drinkType) ...
```

But the `is` keyword only allows a class name after it.

Is there another way to check if `someDrink` inherits a given type?

Refactoring isn't *totally* out of the question if you can suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Umm, according to the documentation on [System.Object.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx), it returns the *exact* runtime type of the object. So it will never return `Drink` in your case. Maybe there is something wrong with the code calling your method.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure - you can use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
if (drinkType.IsAssignableFrom(someDrink.GetType()))
```

Note that it's important that you don't get the target of the call and the argument the wrong way round. I have to consult the docs every time I use it, which is fortunately rarely :)

Comment: Just so I don't have to parse through the question every time I find this question on Google every couple of months, that's `if (parentType.IsAssignableFrom(child.GetType())`.